# CSV Not able append text as some rows understood as text and some rows and number

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, csv

I have a excel with a one column. That is imported from Mangento tool.
One of the row value is

> 7,81,90

and one of the row value is

> 71,08,19,11,31,614

First row understood as text however second row understood as number from MS Excel.

I want to append ",677" to all rows but those row are understood in number format appears like this

> 677,7108191131614

Any solution for this?

Comment: Are you saying you want to append each row adding the characters ",677" after the last character of each row... and your current file is a comma delimited csv file?

Comment: No... "71,08,19,11,31,614" should be treated as string so that i can append ",677" at the end. Lets forget that its a CSV for a moment.

Comment: Why not use a Text editor  ???

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your requirement correctly, here is how to do this. Consider the spreadsheet below:

[image: Original Table]

The values in red are the numbers you gave. Note that I have added the first 3 numbers (cells A3 to A4) to show that this works for text or numbers. The 3 text values below your examples (cells A7 to A9) were added just to include some additional examples.

If I click on cell B2 and enter the formula:

```
=A2&",617"
```

and then copy this to the other cells in column B the outcome will be as follows:

[image: Table with Formula]

I hope this is what you were looking for.